# Not able to pass proper image to tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am having 2 structs as given below:

```
struct ProductImage {
   let id : String
   let url : URL
   let isDefault : Bool
}

struct Product {
    let name : String
    let id : String
    var images = [ProductImage]()

    init(name : String, id: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
    }

    mutating func add(image: ProductImage) {
        images.append(image)
    }
}
```

Now I have a collectionview which has some cells on it with each having an image and a name label and an id label with it. It also has a button and when I click on it, the image on the collectionview cell and also the name and id is shown in a tableviewcell and stored in an array. After returning back and clicking the button of the 2nd `collectionview` item, I will see 2 cells now.(Both the 1st and the 2nd). That I'm doing like so...

```
func SellBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

   let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPath(for: ((sender.superview?.superview) as! RecipeCollectionViewCell))

   self.photoThumbnail = self.arrayOfURLImages[(indexPath?.row)!]

   let myVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "productSellIdentifier") as! sellTableViewController

   let productObject = productData1[(indexPath?.row)!]

        if selectedItems == nil {
          selectedItems = [Product(name:productObject.name, id: productObject.id)]

        } else {
            selectedItems?.append(productObject)

         }
      myVC.arrProduct = selectedItems
        navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true) }
```

But my issue is I'm not able to pass the right image like I do the name and id. In my case the name & id passed is proper but the image passed is wrong. How can I fix it...?

**EDIT:** The parsing of json where both the image and other data is added to the array is given like so

```
     var theProduct = Product(name: name, id: id, theRate: rate, quantity: qty, sku: skuCode, prdCateg: prodCat, prodDescr: description)
     if let images = anItem["product_images"] as? [[String:String]] {
     for image in images {
     guard let imageId = image["id"],
     let url1 = image["image"],
     let isDefault = image["is_default"] else {continue}
     print(imageId)
     let productImage = ProductImage(id: imageId, url: URL(string: url1)!, isDefault: isDefault == "1")
     theProduct.add(image: productImage) //image is added here
     self.productData1.append(theProduct)

     let url = URL(string: url1)
     let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
     self.arrayOfURLImages.append(UIImage(data: data!)!)
     self.appDelegate.commonArrayForURLImages = self.arrayOfURLImages
```

**EDIT 2:**

This is how I'm assigning the images and other data in the tableviewcell. This is the code of cellForRow..(of the tableview from where the cells are loaded..)

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: sellTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sellProductIdentifier") as! sellTableViewCell

 cell.prdImgView?.image = self.appDelegate.commonArrayForURLImages[indexPath.row]                              

    let product = arrProduct?[indexPath.row]
        cell.produvtNameLabel.text = product?.name
        cell.rateTextField.text = product?.theRate

         return cell
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `indexPath.item` instead of `indexPath.row` when assigning to `self.photoThumbnail` ? Rows are in table views, collection views operate on items, since you can have more than one cell in a row, or you may not have clear rows.

Comment: @Losiowaty..that's not the issue...

Comment: Where you have called your `add(image: ProductImage)` method

Comment: Where you are adding images to selected items?

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani the add(image: ProductImage) is called while parsing through the json to get specific elements...I have edited the question and added that snippet...

Comment: @ViniApp Currently I have not added images to selectedItems. That I've tried to do like so..var productImage = ProductImage(id: imgObj.id, url: imgObj.url, isDefault: imgObj.isDefault) , param.add(image: productImage) & selectedItems.append(param). But the array that gives image to cell.imageview.image is not getting the proper image...

Comment: `var theProduct = Product(name: name, id: id, theRate: rate, quantity: qty, sku: skuCode, prdCateg: prodCat, prodDescr: description)`
This is different from your structure!
 `theProduct.add(image: productImage) //image is added here`

Comment: How you are accessing image in `cellForRow`?

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani But after adding image to `theProduct`, I'm also adding them into an array and its from this array that the images are shown (have added 2 more lines of code in the edit).  In the tableviewcontroller from where the cells are loaded, it is from the array `self.appDelegate.commonArrayForURLImages` that I'm assigning the images. This is causing the issue.  But how the image at the specific index has to be obtained from this array, I'm confused...

Comment: @ViniApp I have added that in the EDIT 2 part in the question

Comment: You can access directly like this `product?.images[0]` right. Why you are trying to access images from `self.appDelegate.commonArrayForURLImages`?

Comment: @ViniApp I just assigned the value of `arrayOfUrlImages` which gets its value from json to another common array and then used it in the 'tableviewcontroller' also. It does give contain the array required..but not the one at the specific index. When I give something like what I mentioned in EDIT 2, the images are shown in sequence in the `tableviewcell`(i.e. the img of 1st collcn view item, then the img of 2nd collecn view item and so on... ) and not the image at the particular index...

Comment: Try by accessing image as product?.images[0]

Comment: No..it won't work, @ViniApp

Answer (score 1):

I think issue is in image loaded asynchronously,
For downloading image it takes some time, It is possible that wrong image is assigned to a cell once it gets downloaded.

Try this https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Comment: No @Sandy..that is not the issue...the image at the particular index is not sent properly from the structs. Once that is achieved, the issue can be fixed.But how that is done that I'm not sure...